# How to regex negative number and dashes?

Tags: regex, postgresql

I am new to regex and I have a confusing problem with regards to this scenario where I have a list of items with their weight and unit. I need to abbreviate the item and the weight however my regex broke when there is a negative number. Here is my current regex:

```
[.0-9]+-\.?[0-9.]*
```

And here is my example case that is working

```
Lenovo Legion 5-15 lbs
```

I was able to match 5-15 and that is correct however when I have a value like

```
DELL XPS -2 lbs
```

My regex broke. How can I modify my regex to accommodate the negative value?

Comment: Maybe `-?[.0-9]+(?:-[0-9.]+)?` Or `-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/UdQgHF/1))?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew. Thank you very much -?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)?)? work on my test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/UdQgHF/1)

*Details*:

- `-?` - an optional `-`
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - one or more digits and then an optional occurrence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `(?:-\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?` - an optional occurrence of

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` - one or more digits and then an optional occurrence of a `.` and one or more digits

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the effort and help! :)